# My iPod classic won't load music from my new computer

Tags: sync, ipod

The machine I used to sync my iPod classic to recently died an untimely death.  Fortunately I had a backup of my music library and restored that to a replacement computer which I have authorized thorough iTunes (same operating system and same version of iTunes). I took a bit of time to clean up my iTunes library and also got some new downloads (from Amazon) which have been added to my library.  When I connect my iPod it appears in iTunes and says it's syncing but it doesn't download any of the new music or clean up any of the stuff I deleted from iTunes.  It just shows that it's syncing for a few seconds and then says "OK to disconnect".  I've moved between computers in the past and never has this sort of problem.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are we talking OS X or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to perform a [reset on the iPod](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/classic/#):

```
To reset your iPod: 
1. Toggle the Hold switch on and off (Slide it to Hold, then turn it off again) 
2. Press and hold the Menu and Center (Select) buttons simultaneously until the 
Apple logo appears, about 6 to 10 seconds. You may need to repeat this step.
```

If you're still having problems, after that I would try a [restore to defaults](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1339):

> How to restore iPod
>
> 1. Verify that you have an active Internet connection, because you may need to download new versions of the iTunes and iPod Software.
> 2. Download and install the latest version of iTunes if necessary.
> 3. Open iTunes. Connect your iPod to your computer using the USB or FireWire cable that came with your iPod.
> 4. After a few moments, your iPod will appear in the Source panel in iTunes.
> 5. Select your iPod in the Source panel. You will see information about your iPod appear in the Summary tab of the main iTunes window.
> 6. Click Restore.
> 7. If you are using a Mac, you will be asked to enter an administrator’s name and password.
> 8. A progress bar will appear on the computer screen, indicating that stage one of the restore process has begun. When this stage is done,
>      iTunes will present one of two messages with instructions specific to
>      the iPod model you are restoring.
> 9. Disconnect iPod and connect it to iPod Power Adapter (typically applies to older iPod models).
> 10. Leave iPod connected to computer to complete restore (typically applies newer iPod models).
> 11. During stage two of the restore process, the iPod displays an Apple logo as well as a progress bar at the bottom of the display. It
>       is critical that the iPod remain connected to the computer or iPod
>       power adapter during this stage.  Note: The progress bar may be
>       difficult to see, because the backlight on the iPod display may be
>       off.
> 12. After stage two of the restore process is complete, the iTunes Setup Assistant window will appear. It will ask you to name your iPod
>       and choose your syncing preferences, as it did when you connected your
>       iPod for the first time.

Comment: please try your best to include in your answer all the relevant points instead of using a plain link. if the link ever gets broken so does your whole answer.